# fgets() boundary case prevents waiting for input

Tags: fgets

There are many questions about fgets() on this forum, but none of them have provided me with the answer to this particular problem.

I have been brushing up on some very old C skills and have been following the tutorial on cprogramming.com.

I have a problem with the string.h example of lesson 9 (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>    /* stdin, printf, and fgets */
#include <string.h>   /* for all the new-fangled string functions */

/* this function is designed to remove the newline from the end of a string
entered using fgets.  Note that since we make this into its own function,
we could easily choose a better technique for removing the newline.  Aren't
functions great? */
void strip_newline( char *str, int size )
{
    int i;

    /* remove the null terminator */
    for (  i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        if ( str[i] == '\n' )
        {
            str[i] = '\0';

            /* we're done, so just exit the function by returning */
            return;   
        }
    }
    /* if we get all the way to here, there must not have been a newline! */
}

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    char lastname[50];
    char fullname[100]; /* Big enough to hold both name and lastname */

    printf( "Please enter your name: " );
    fgets( name, 50, stdin );

    /* see definition above */
    strip_newline( name, 50 );

    /* strcmp returns zero when the two strings are equal */
    if ( strcmp ( name, "Alex" ) == 0 ) 
    {
        printf( "That's my name too.\n" );
    }
    else                                     
    {
        printf( "That's not my name.\n" );
    }
    // Find the length of your name
    printf( "Your name is %d letters long", strlen ( name ) );
    printf( "Enter your last name: " );
    fgets( lastname, 50, stdin );
    strip_newline( lastname, 50 );
    fullname[0] = '\0';            
    /* strcat will look for the \0 and add the second string starting at
       that location */
    strcat( fullname, name );     /* Copy name into full name */
    strcat( fullname, " " );      /* Separate the names by a space */
    strcat( fullname, lastname ); /* Copy lastname onto the end of fullname */
    printf( "Your full name is %s\n",fullname );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

It all works well for normal cases, but if the input for fgets() is 49 characters long - which should be allowed, as I understand it, given that the buffer has 50 slots - the second call to fgets() does not wait for input.

The other answers I've seen talk about clearing the buffer before calling fgets(), but even setting the first character of the buffer (`lastname[0] = '\0\` doesn't work.

I'm sure I'm overlooking the blindingly obvious, but if somebody could put me out of my misery, I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a call to

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

Either before or after your call to `fgets`, to flush any extra characters from the buffer.